# Google authentication services migration - how to make sure the process was completd successfully?

Tags: java, google-plus, google-oauth, google-openid

Google has announced they are migrating their authentication services to consolidate the way the APIs work and supposedly make them "simpler". We want to make sure our app will work but are not really sure if the steps we've taken are enough.

We have a Java server app which uses `google-oauth-client` and its `AuthorizationCodeFlow` to authorize users. We have a client ID for web application created in Google Developers Console. We have defined a redirect URI there as well.
We use the key and secret from developers console to create GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. When creating an authorization URL from that object we provide a redirect url defined in the developers console.

We have changed the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" to "email" (we use it to call `plus.people().get("me")` now instead of `oauth2.userinfo().v2().me().get()`). In the end the scopes we provide when creating GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow are "email", "openid" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar".

We use the obtained token to manipulate user's calendar and to find out user's email.

We feel the documentation on how the whole authorization works and the migration guides are a little bit too distributed and it is hard to understand the fundamentals behind this whole process.

When developing our app we have made the best effort to fully understand OAuth 2.0 and how it works with Google APIs. We have read documentation, participated in OAuth 2.0 workshop and followed Google's guides. We thought we have a fairly good understanding of what's happening behind the scenes. With this migration guide however, our confusion arised. Are we actually using OAuth 2.0 login? Are we using OpenID 2.0 (since we use opeind and email scope s to receive user's email along with the token)? Are we using OpenID+OAuth hybrid? All of those options have separate subguides on how to migrate and this doesn't help with confusion. So the question we have is: will this setup work after the migration process is over? Do we misunderstand something?

Comment: Why not just set up a test environment and test it?

Comment: What do you mean, how do we set up a test environment with how the Google domains will look after their migration is completed? We would very gladly do that.

Comment: Could you provide a link to 'Google has announced...'? If https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration is what you mean, it's not a Google migrating somewhere, but your app have to.

Comment: If you'd read the linked website you'd see that they are deprecating and disabling the way authorization used to work when we were designing our app.

Comment: If you followed guideline, and are sure that you use no deprecated methods, what would your question sound like? Will it work? If you can't test it, there will be no prompt answer.

Comment: Yes, you've read the question properly :) Will the proposed setup work correctly. I have detailed our setup in order to receive help from someone who might know more than I do. Or perhaps find if there indeed IS a way to test the setup on how the OAuth will work after the switch.

Comment: There is no "switch" the deprecated way of authenticating and the supported way of authenticating are both live. All you have to do is stop using the old method, start using the new method and you are done.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the announcement you are referring to? (ie, "Google has announced they are migrating their authentication services").

Could you also provide a sample HTTP request generated by your app to do authN/Z with Google will be of great help answering your questions (eg, "which protocol is your app using for login?") -- feel free to remove client-specific info (eg, client-id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We experienced no trouble with oauth after the switchver date which means the steps we've taken (those enumarated in our question) were enough and the services work fine.